# a good guide to "Audio Queue Services"?

Tags: ios, core-audio, audioqueue

after looking on apple's example "SpeakHere" i got a little confused and i am looking for any guide for more basic practice. my goal finally is to create 2 sec audio "Chunks" and hand it over to the server (while recording).

if anyone know a good reference i would like to know.
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a good published resource on the Audio Queue API, look into the book "Learning Core Audio" by Adamson and Avila.

Answer (score 0):

Core Audio and Audio Queue Services can be pretty gnarly to wade through.  Check out "The Amazing Audio Engine", which is an Objective C wrapper to core audio that takes care of a lot of the low-level stuff for you.